# nvcc compiler not optimizing

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, nvcc

Why is the compiler not doing some trivial optimizations that can be done in the kernel? I have the following code for matrix multiplication:

```
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
        int numARows, int numAColumns,
        int numBRows, int numBColumns,
        int numCRows, int numCColumns) {

    int n=numAColumns;
    int Row=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int Col=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    if((Row<numCRows) && (Col<numCColumns)){
        for(int k=0;k<n;++k){
                    C[Row*numCColumns+Col]+=
                        A[Row*numAColumns+k]*B[k*numBColumns+Col];
        }
    }   
}
```

The example would go much faster if I use a temporal register `Cvalue` to store the sum:

```
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
        int numARows, int numAColumns,
        int numBRows, int numBColumns,
        int numCRows, int numCColumns) {

    int n=numAColumns;
    int Row=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int Col=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    if((Row<numCRows) && (Col<numCColumns)){
        float Cvalue=0;
        for(int k=0;k<n;++k){
            Cvalue+=A[Row*numAColumns+k]*B[k*numBColumns+Col];
        }
        C[Row*numCColumns+Col]=Cvalue;
    }   
}
```

In the last case, global memory for `C` is accessed only once whereas in the first case it is accessed many times in the loop. Isn't this kind of optimizations normally done by compilers? Both codes have a difference of about 30% in performance in my tests, I'm doing nvcc -O3 ...

Comment: The code is not the same. I think you wanted `C[Row*numCColumns+Col]+=` instead of `C[Row*numCColumns+Col]=`.

Comment: Sorry, yes... I corrected it.

Comment: since C could be accessed by a different thread during the calculation, the code would not be the same.

Comment: Also you don't zero C in the first example.

Comment: I think I get it now, so basically there is no enough info for the compiler to take this step.

Comment: @Dave: Since there are no barriers, what another thread might do is irrelevant.  The real problem is that `C` might overlap with (or be the same matrix as) `A` or `B`, which makes the two routines very different.

Comment: Can confirm. I used `float * __restrict__ C` for both codes and now the times for both are pretty much the same.

Comment: Note that the first code depends on the output matrix being zeroed on entry to the function; the second works correctly regardless of whether the output matrix is zeroed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `C` is not declared as `__restrict__` the compiler cannot know whether `C` is the same matrix as `A` or `B`, so it cannot perform the optimization mentioned. When I instead used `float* __restrict__ C`, the times for both became practically the same. Thanks Chris Dodd.

Comment: Standard C uses `restrict`; `__restrict__` is something else altogether.  Or, rather, it could be something else altogether.  On the whole, you're better off using the standard name than a non-standard, potentially compiler-specific extension.